# nivo slider show delay

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, nivo-slider

I am using Nivo Slider plugin. The question is that when the first image have not disappeared completely, the part of the second image is also displayed. Usually it is located at the bottom area of the first image.

The code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
            slices: 15, // For slice animations
            boxCols: 8, // For box animations
            boxRows: 4, // For box animations
            animSpeed: 300, // Slide transition speed
            pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
            startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
            directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
            controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
            controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
            pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
            manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
            prevText: '<<', // Prev directionNav text
            nextText: '>>', // Next directionNav text
            randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
            beforeChange: function () { }, // Triggers before a slide transition
            afterChange: function () { }, // Triggers after a slide transition
            slideshowEnd: function () { }, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
            lastSlide: function () { }, // Triggers when last slide is shown
            afterLoad: function () { } // Triggers when slider has loaded
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

We will need to see your CSS as well. It could be that the .entry-content or other CSS is showing a little too much behind the scenes action.